# Query a limited items from the database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm working on a Spring application and I need to update every user in a database (around 4500 records).

My code works well in my local environment with a few users, but I'm afraid in the testing environments and even in live it will be extremly slow if I get every user from the database.

Here is my code so far:

```
public void syncUsers() {
        List<User> usersList = userService.getAllUsers();
        usersList.stream().forEach((user) -> {
            if (isNull(user.getSocialId())) {
                String id = socialRestAPIService.syncContacts(user);
                user.setSocialId(id);
                userService.updateUser(user);
            }
        });
    }
```

This one is the `userService.getAllUsers` method:

```
public List<User> getAllUsers () {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
```

What I want to achive is update 100 users in one time and then update the next 100 so on...
How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `userRepository` is a `JpaRepository` then it implements the `PagingAndSortingRepository` which has a method
[findAll(Pageable pageable)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html#findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)).

Hence, you can create a `Pageable` like this:

```
Pageable.ofSize(100).withPage(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pageable and while loop to fetch all data by limit until fetch all of them. example:

```
public void syncUsers() {
    int pageSize = 100;
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, pageSize, Sort.by("id"));

    Page<User> userPage;
    do {
        userPage = userService.getAllUsers(pageable);
        List<User> usersList = userPage.getContent();

        usersList.stream().forEach((user) -> {
            if (isNull(user.getSocialId())) {
                String id = socialRestAPIService.syncContacts(user);
                user.setSocialId(id);
                userService.updateUser(user);
            }
        });

        pageable = pageable.next();
    } while (userPage.hasNext());
}
```